# ASP.NET image(BLOB) retrieve from database(mysql)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to retrieve image from database and show in gridview here the code for ObjectDataSource associated with gridview for better understanding giving this code...thanks in advance

```
public static List<Users> GetAllUser()
{
   List<Users> UsersList = new List<Users>();

   string connection_string = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;";
   using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connection_string))
   {
       MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select * from smart_shop.users order by id desc", connection);
       connection.Open();
       MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          Users userObject = new Users();

          userObject.userName = reader["name"].ToString();
          userObject.image = reader["image"].ToString();   //Here variable 'image' is string type but in database BLOB            

          UsersList.Add(userObject);
       }

   }

   return UsersList;
}
```

and the gridview code is

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;User Information</h3>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" CssClass="dataGridTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-Height="30" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCreated="GridView2_RowCreated" PageSize="20">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="userName" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="userName" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="image">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="30px" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
            </asp:GridView>


            <br />
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllUser" TypeName="OnlineSmartShop.SettingsDataAccessLayer"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])(e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["image"];
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            (e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as Image).ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the content type set in the imageurl?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying here ImageUrl is the keyword?

Comment: The string "data:image/png;" added in the ImageUrl is the content-type of the image which represents the type of the image. So I was suggesting to check if that value is correct with respect to the image data. It might be that the image is jpeg or other format. In such cases setting png would not work.

Comment: What should I do now i'm using always png and jpg image format ,stored in  database BLOB format

Comment: If you know the type of images you have stored in the db then you should use the content type accordingly. Also you might want to check if you are able to retrieve entire byte array from the db. Sometimes it happens that only 8000 bytes retrieved from the db.

Answer (score 0):

reader["image"] contains byte[]

```
 while (reader.Read())
   {
      Users userObject = new Users();

      userObject.userName = reader["name"].ToString();
      userObject.image = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])reader["image"]);              

      UsersList.Add(userObject);
   }
```

and change itemdatabound event. row item type is Users..

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Users rowUser = e.Row.DataItem as Users;

            (e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as Image).ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + rowUser.image;
        }
    }
```

PS: **This method can cause performance problems**